# More elegant way to replace all field equal to Null by the default value in django model objects

Tags: python-3.x, django

I'am looking on a more elegant way to replace all field of my model objects which are equals to Null by the default value defined in the model.

Here is my current code :

```
for buy in Buy.objects.all():
    for f in Buy._meta.get_fields():
        field = eval("buy." + f.name)
        if field is None:
            field = Buy._meta.get_field(f.name).get_default()
        buy.save()
```

But i find the use of eval not elegant.
If anyone have better way to do that

Regards

Comment: Just to confirm, are you trying to *"permanently replace the values"* ?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu yes :)

Answer (score 2):

Could you say:

```
for buy in Buy.objects.all()
    for f in Buy.meta.get_fields():
        if f is None:
            buy._meta.get_field(f.name).get_default()
        buy.save()
```